# What is the difference between uniform convergence and dominate convergence theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I saw that **both have aim to change limit with integral**... that's the part that interests me most.

I saw in some cases where we couldn't use uniform convergence, we use dominate convergence theorem to change limit with integral, and vice versa when we couldn't use dominate convergence...

> Exist a difference between uniform convergence and dominated convergence when we change limit with integral? If yes, what give in addition each other ?
>
> Suppose there is a case when we can use both, does it matter that we use?

Comment: One of the two only deals with integration over a compact set. Additionally, the assumptions needed for the dominated convergence theorem are weaker (easier to satisfy) in many cases. (If you are in a situation where both apply, then it's indifferent -- use the one you like the most, or the one that you feel is the less "Hammer-like.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we work on a compact set: The uniform convergence theorem uses a much stronger assumption on the nature of the convergence of your sequence of functions. It roughly says that if the sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ you can exchange limit and integration.

The dominated convergence theorem requires $f_n$ only to converge pointwise almost everywhere to $f$ and there needs to be an integrable bound $g$ such that
$|f_n|\leqslant |g|$ almost everywhere.

Actually, the latter theorem implies the former as uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence and it's easy to construct an upper bound from the uniform convergence.

Comment: conditions of former (=first) $\Rightarrow$ conditions of latter (=last) is what you meant to say, right?

Comment: No, the Dominated CV theorem implies the Uniform one, as the latter requires stronger assumptions: if you meet the assumptions of the UCV, then you can apply the DCV anyway.

Comment: look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem from  "Discussion of the assumptions"   why $\lim _{n\to \infty }\int _0^1\:f_n\left(x\right)dx$ is not equal with $\int _0^1\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\:f_n\left(x\right)dx$ ?

Comment: It is under some assumptions, not always. It's the whole point of these theorems -- without these assumptions, some "crazy" counterexamples exist.